# Very high memory usage with nothing running

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, memory

I'm running Arch Linux with GNOME 3.38 X11, and have an issue where I'm at idle (after using the computer for a while and closing everything) using around 8-9GB of RAM.

I know about [linxatemyram](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/), and I don't think this is the issue, since `free -m` prints the following:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           62282        9059       29502         162       23720       52368
Swap:           8191           0        8191
```

Indicating that indeed I am using a lot of ram when running nothing. When I used to have 16GB I would also run out of memory frequently due to this issue, so I don't think it's some form of caching, since that would back down when my memory usage goes up.

Curiously the `top` memory usages don't add up to the amount it claims to have reserved either. [Here's a paste of the results I get](https://pastebin.com/TKqNSrfK). I've been thinking for a while that something must be leaking, but I can't seem to find out what.

EDIT: Extra outputs. These were measured soon after a restart, so aren't representative. I will rerun and post after the same situation arises.

```
$ mount | grep tmpfs
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=31848276k,nr_inodes=7962069,mode=755,inode64)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755,inode64)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,size=4096k,nr_inodes=1024,mode=755,inode64)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=31888716k,nr_inodes=409600,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=6377740k,nr_inodes=1594435,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=985,inode64)
```

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev              31G     0   31G   0% /dev
run              31G  1.7M   31G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3  450G  208G  219G  49% /
tmpfs            31G  737M   30G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            31G   19M   31G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           6.1G  136K  6.1G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: `mount | grep tmpfs` ? `df -h` ?

Comment: I just restarted in order to do work today. Should I do this while the system has high RAM usage or is anytime fine?

Comment: You might have `tmpfs` mounted to `/tmp` and programs writing tons of data to it, which will eat your RAM and will **not** be shown by `top` unforunately

Comment: Good suggestion! I added the information you requested.

Comment: `smem` can show more accurate information than `top`. Some useful parameters are `smem -wkt` for the system-wide totals, `smem -mkt` for file / shared memory mappings, and `smem -kt` for per-process values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided you indeed have `tmpfs` filesystems mounted at `/tmp` and `/dev/shm` which are not shown by `top` or other similar utilities.

Please, monitor these mount points usage via `df` and clean up data or stop applications writing data to them. Some applications create files and delete them right away and such files still take space. They can't be seen directly via e.g. `ls` or `df` but you can discover them this way:

```bsh
sudo lsof -n | egrep "/tmp|/dev/shm" | grep deleted
```

Since this is the 20th time I'm seeing this question I've gone ahead and filed bug reports against `top`, `free` and `htop`:

https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/issues/196

https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/issues/556

Comment: I share your reasoning, but I can't reproduce the OP's issue on my Arch: the size of a file created in a tmpfs `/tmp` shows up in `free`'s `shared` (and `Shmem` in `/proc/meminfo`). If the file is deleted while used by a process, its size is counted either in `/proc/meminfo`'s `Shmem` (showing up in `free`'s `shared`) or in `/proc/meminfo`'s `AnonPages` (then showing up in `top`'s `RES` for the process). It seems to never "disappear" - though of course there may be something I missed.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is the 9GB of used memory, then run top and list processes by %MEM.

Perfectly normal. Linux, Windows and most other OSes like to cache everything they can. Memory is being used, but its not locked to that content. It can be freed and replaced with something else as fast as the disk reads roll.
You should only see lots of free memory when a big process (or a set of collectively big processes) just ended.

Comment: He seems to be asking about the `used` column reading 9 GB. Your answer appears to apply to the `buff/cache` column reading of 23 GB.